Error while adding Stripe payment gateway in my Flutterapp
A problem occurred while configuring root project 'android'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.9.25.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.9.25)
> Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.9.25/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.9.25.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.9.25/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.9.25.jar'.
> repo.maven.apache.org


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Do you have any solution for this?
